# Facebook Like Box integration

Tags: html, facebook, plugins

I am working for a website and need to integrate a Facebook Like Box.

I've put in the Facebook ID, then it generates some code but [I am not able to click on the XFBML IFRAME and URL Button to generate the codes, only HTML5 Button](http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3151/3ebjckv3_png.htm).

So far I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Under Construction</title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">



</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/RW-    Fliesen/115860578491339" data-width="292" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="light" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

which gives me [this output](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3151/p57fij5m_png.htm).

But I need the whole Like Box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ if we create like button we will get the code as you shown in the link...

If we inspect the source code( in mozilla or chrome) you can see 
`<a class="uiPillButton" href="#" id="button-xfbml">XFBML</a>` for the link XFBML.

Since the href= # it will not show any other page...
facebook may be working on that

Comment: I´m sure the contents are updated via some ajax request, so when theres a script doing so with selector id="button-xfbml", it is quite right to set the href to "#"  to stay in same document

Comment: Yes, but on searching the full source code we could not find any jquery function call related to the class uiPillButton or id button-xfbml

Comment: it´s facebook! whatever they do, it´s nearly impossible to retrace it. Maybe they are forced by  
stock market to force developers to use their hacky js sdk and html5 syntax

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem,
there is an error in the script src, `"http:"` is missing

take a look at the image  : http://solarlogos.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/facebook-like-box-bug/

Comment: OK, but I am not able to click on the XFBML IFRAME and URL Button to generate the codes, only HTML5 Button is activated for some reason.

Comment: ah sorry i read too fast, just tried myself and the links are not working, maybe facebook itself is working on.

Comment: Well that could be a reason for that. Thank you I will wait if it works later then.